facing a problem with managing state in React javaScript
I am trying to toggle the 'checked-radio-btn' class and show or hide some content based on this class. It gets applied on the first click, but it doesn't get removed from the previous element when selecting another element. I want only one element selected at a time.
gitHub link for full code - https://github.com/Mazhar1857/practice
function ProjectItem({ productName, totalPledge, productDescription, totalLeft, index }) {

    const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState('')

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(isActive)
    }, [isActive]);

    const handleCheckedProduct = (value) => {
        setIsActive(value);
    }

    return (
        <div className={`product ${index === isActive ? 'checked-radio-btn' : ''} ${index}`} >
            <input type="radio" name='product' id={productName} value={totalPledge} onClick={() => { handleCheckedProduct(index) }} />
            <label className='radio-btn' htmlFor={productName} onClick={() => { handleCheckedProduct(index) }}></label>
            <div className='product-name'>
                <label htmlFor={productName} onClick={() => { handleCheckedProduct(index) }}>{productName}</label><span>Pledge ${totalPledge} or more</span>
            </div>
            <div className='product-left'>
                <span>{totalLeft}</span><span>left</span>
            </div>
            <div className='product-description'>{productDescription}</div>
            <div className={`back-product ${index === isActive ? 'checked-radio-btn' : ''}`}>
                <div>Enter your pledge</div>
                <div className='project-pledge-btn' >
                    <div className='project-input-btn'>
                        <input type='text' defaultValue={totalPledge} />
                    </div>
                    <button>continue</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
} 

component's state is not updating, based on which i am trying to toggle my class

my gitHub repository for full code -- https://github.com/Mazhar1857/practice

if you have multiple items and only one of them should be active, you must define the state in the parent component and pass the value to the items. Also, you can pass some functions as props to the item components which you can call in the item components to mutate the state. Here is an example:
const items = [
    {id: 1, name: "one" },
    {id: 2, name: "two" },
    {id: 3, name: "three" },
];

function ParentComponent() {
    const [activeId, setActiveId] = useState(items[0].id);

    return <>
        {items.map(({id, name}) => 
            <Item 
                key={id} 
                isActive={activeId === id} 
                onSelect={() => setActiveId(id)}
                name={name}
            />
        )}
    </>
}

function Item({ id, isActive, onSelect, name }){
    return <p onClick={() => onSelect()}>
        {name} is {isActive ? "": "not"} active
    </p>
}

